# How can I undo what CCleaner did?

Tags: google-chrome, ccleaner, session-restore

I experienced a little problem when using CCleaner. Before I started, I had two Chrome windows opened with multiple tabs each. Then I ran CCleaner and it asked me to close Chrome in order to delete the history. I closed it and ran CCleaner. After that I opened Chrome and only one of the windows restored. Since the other window contained important sites I need to visit, and I can’t remember them, is there a way to restore it? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The only way to do this would be using a data recovery tool that might be able to recover the files Chrome uses to save the session. Anyways: don't delete data you might need, I exclude Chrome from CCleaner because I don't want to close it and reload the cache to there are more reasons not to clean it.

Comment: Well, it was the first time I use any cleaner, so I lacked experience. Any reccomendations on what data recovery tool to use? Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, was your google chrome synced with your google account? if yes, then visit [Google web history](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity), there is a chance that you might get some of the web links you visited.

Comment: Yes, chrome was synced with gmail, but there is only history, and I haven't visited these sites for a long, they just stayed opened for whenever I have time. So I don't need history, I want to restore the tabs.

Comment: try [easeus data recovery](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.html) to recover the data for AppData folder.

Comment: thanks bro! but i didnt really manage to go through the recovery :/  firstly, in the appdata folder there is quite a lot stuff, and after that, if i want to actually recover the files, i have to purchase the paid version of easeus, since the free trial is only able to find the files, not to recover them. do you have any ideas for me? it would be great if you do!
p.s. i tried to attach a screenshot of the program, but i could not.

Comment: you can recover 2 GB data with free version. And, only scan this folder AppData\Local\Google\Chrome.

Comment: nope, it does not work, thanks for the assistance though

Answer (score -1):

In Ccleaner cleaning go to second tab, chrome section and unmark session. This prevent session to be lost due Ccleaner actions.

Can do same for FF, O, and Edge but not IE.

Comment: Add some reference and detail supporting what you state or delete this and wait until you have enough rep to start commenting.